# @Cacheable condition using application properties

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to use Redis with Spring's `@Cacheable` but need to conditionally turn caching on or off based on a Spring Boot style application property. My first attempt doesn't seem to work.

The application.properties file:

```
auth.token-cache-enabled=false
```

The properties class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "auth")
public class AuthProperties {
    public boolean tokenCacheEnabled;
    ...
}
```

The service method annotation:

```
@Cacheable(key = "#token", condition = "@authProperties.tokenCacheEnabled()")
```

Results in:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1057E:(pos 1): No bean resolver registered in the context to resolve access to bean 'authProperties' at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.BeanReference.getValueInternal(BeanReference.java:48)
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is or if there's another way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried this? "#{authProperties.tokenCacheEnabled()}"

Comment: That was actually the first thing I tried, but I just double checked and that results in: `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 1): Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)' at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.InternalSpelExpressionParser.raiseInternalException(InternalSpelExpressionParser.java:976)`

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to make this work in my situation, but I also found a bug ticket for what I believe is the same issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13812

My workaround is to `@Inject` my `AuthProperties` in to the service containing the method I want to cache. Next, I changed the method's cache condition to this:

```
    @Cacheable(key = "#token", condition = "#root.target.authProperties.tokenCacheEnabled")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass `tokenCacheEnabled` as input to method and use `condition ="#tokenCacheEnabled == true"`